# Why won't the ball in the Katamari Damacy Reroll demo move?

Tags: nintendo-switch, katamari-damacy

I recently downloaded the demo for the Katamari Damacy Reroll on the Nintendo Switch and I don't think the demo comes with the tutorial.

My wife and I have moved the character towards/around the ball, but it didn't move.

I can't find anywhere that details how to move the ball in the game. Just this [guide](https://www.google.com/amp/s/www.imore.com/katamari-damacy-reroll-beginners-guide%3famp) which says to follow the tutorial.

Comment: Did you notice the part in your linked guide where it says you can change the control scheme? Those usually display the controls, so figure out how to open the menu. FWIW, the PlayStation versions all used both sticks to move the katamari.

Comment: @pboss3010 I did see that part. All it says is that they're unintuitive, but they recommend the Simple Controls. We couldn't figure out how to open the menu.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Moving in Katamari is indeed unintuive at first. To move forward you must push **BOTH** Thumbsticks forward. Turning left or right requires pushing one stick up and the other down, like you are pushing with one hand and pulling with the other. Pushing both thumbsticks to the left or right will strafe.